# Problem with multithreading and File options c#

Tags: c#, file

my goal is to create a output file which parse all url in result.

My problem : 
I use Paralelism and he can't be associated with File because it's secured,
i try to put a lock, and i think i don't put it correctly
message error is :
The process cannot access because it is being used by another process the file

What i want :
result is saved in a txt file

Code :

```
//VARIABLE
        List<string> dorklist = File.ReadAllLines("dorks.txt").ToList();
        int numdork = File.ReadAllLines("dorks.txt").Length;
        int totalurls = File.ReadAllLines("Queue.txt").Length;
        int chekeddork = 0;
        int errors = 0;
        File.Create("Queue.txt");
        //TITLE

        Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            while (true) {
                Console.Title = ("PARSER | " + chekeddork + "/" + numdork + " URLS : " + totalurls);
                Thread.Sleep(100);
            }
        });
        //BOUCLE
        Parallel.ForEach(dorklist, new ParallelOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 100 }, dorklist => {
            try
            {
                using (HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest())
                {
                    //HEADERS
                    req.AddHeader(HttpHeader.UserAgent, "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.14; rv:65.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/65.0");

                    //REQUESTS
                    var content = req.Get("https://www.google.com/search?q="+dorklist);
                    if (Convert.ToString(content.StatusCode) == "OK")
                    {
                        chekeddork++;
                        Console.WriteLine("Dork used : " + dorklist);
                        HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
                        doc.LoadHtml(content.ToString());
                        var links = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[@class='r']//a");
                        foreach (var link in links)
                        {
                            var href = link.Attributes["href"];
                            var result = href.Value.ToString();
                            using (StreamWriter streamaze = new StreamWriter("Queue.txt", true))
                                    {
                                        streamaze.WriteLine(results);
                                        streamaze.Close();
                                    }
                        }


                    }
                    else
                    { Console.WriteLine("Bad");
                        errors++;
                    }

                }
            }
            catch (HttpException)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Banned");
                errors++;
            }
        });
        }

    }
}
```

AND the problem is here : `

```
using (StreamWriter streamaze = new StreamWriter("Queue.txt", true))
                                {
                                    streamaze.WriteLine(results);
                                    streamaze.Close();
```

Because there is Parallel.ForEach and the maxdegree
Thanks to all help me

Comment: You're doing a lot of things in a poor way with this code. You can't do `chekeddork++` inside a `Parallel.ForEach` - you risk a race condition. You can write the same file in a `Parallel.ForEach` either. You've also written your code so that it is a big fat blob of code rather than separating out the functions you're performing.

Comment: Also, don't put locks inside a `Parallel.ForEach` unless you can't possibly avoid it. There's not much point saying you want things to run in parallel and then saying you don't want things to run in parallel.

Answer (score 0):

you cannot be writing to one file from several threads at once via separate opens.

Open separate files per thread and merge afterwards.
Or open the file once before the parallel foreach and , under lock, write to the one open file.
Or put that using inside a lock

```
lock(dorkList) // or create a lock object
{
     using (StreamWriter streamaze = new StreamWriter("Queue.txt", true))
     {
       streamaze.WriteLine(results);
       streamaze.Close();
     }
}
```

or use a specifc lock objecct like this

```
    int chekeddork = 0;
    int errors = 0;
    File.Create("Queue.txt");
    object locker = new Object();
    ....
    lock(locker) // or create a lock object
    {
       using (StreamWriter streamaze = new StreamWriter("Queue.txt", true))
       {
         streamaze.WriteLine(results);
         streamaze.Close();
       }
     }
```

Comment: i try to use lock but idk how it's work it's my first time i use it

Comment: and i don't know how to create the lock object related with that

Comment: stay not work, i have to put the lock(lock) in the foreach right ?

Comment: yes the lock goes inside the parallel for each. The lock object declaration goes before